# Characters other than English are not formatted properly while writing to a file

Tags: python, file-io, string-formatting

I need to write some lines in the file. These lines can be either English or Chinese. I need them in some predefined format. I am using following python code for it.

```
self._file.write(u"%-9s %-21s%-6s %-6s                %%\n" % (stop['stop_id'], stop['stop_name'], self.format_time(stop.get('arrival'), stop.get('exit')), self.format_time(stop.get('departure'), stop.get('enter'))))
```

The stop dictionary is constructed properly. With English names it is formatted correctly but with Chinese names the formatting is not proper. I have attached a screenshot explaining the problem.
[image: Chinese Characters Problem]

Do I need to change the way I write file or some other stuff is needed??

Comment: Try to `open` the file with `encoding='UTF-8'`.

Comment: IT would of interest to see how you opened the file and what encoding the file should be afterwards.

Comment: @KlausD.
It is 
with io.open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
It should be in utf-8 only afterwards

Comment: @Matthias
It is 
with io.open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the formatting is correct. I cannot imagine why Python should change anything in its formatting.

Your problem is that Sublime Text *do not show* the chinese text correctly aligned. It may be caused by the charset used to show chinese characters.

Show an hexadecimal dump of the *incorrect* lines and only then we can say if it is or not a Python problem

That is a common problem in reading mails formatted in a fixed charset like `courrier new` and read with a proportional one like `arial`, even with plain english text using only ascii characters.

I did some tests using UTF-8 characters using 2 bytes in UTF-8 such as `éè` and Python (2.7) correctly formats the unicode strings according to the number of characters and not the number of bytes - sorry I have nothing to deal with chinese words ...

Comment: You are right. No issue of Python, problem with sublime text. As I tried to find the column number of 3rd field, it is the same irrespective of the position at which they seem.